# Is there a way to get the fields and types returned by hive SQL without executing hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, fieldtype

I want to get hive sql result field and type in few seconds ,No matter how complicated SQL is

Comment: You want hive table column names and their data types. right?

Comment: no, I want the SQL result  column names and data type, for example : select count(distinct create_user) as user_count from order where dt='201909' , I want to get   "user_count " and the data type of "user_count"